# How can I create a 3D surface plot in R where 3 variables are used for the coordinates and a 4th variable is used for coloring?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, data-visualization, r-plotly

This is easy to do if you are trying to do a 3D scatter plot. Code below:

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

df = iris

plot_ly(df, 
            x=df$Sepal.Length, 
            y=df$Sepal.Width, 
            z=df$Petal.Length, 
            type="scatter3d", 
            mode="markers", 
            color=df$Petal.Width)
```

The resulting output is:

[image]

I would like to make this a surface plot, but when I change the type to "surface", the image does not render and I get the following warning:

```
'surface' objects don't have these attributes: 'mode', 'marker'
```

Comment: Hey @sdcprez, can you please provide some sample data?

Comment: @Georgery , sdcprez is using the iris dataset included with R. Just do `df = iris` and it runs fine.

Comment: @Paul, yeah, you're right. I guess I wasn't reading thoroughly. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

For plotting a surface, `plot_ly` expects `z` to be a matrix. You can specify color with a `surfacecolor` matrix. `plotly::schema()$traces$surface$meta$description` has some useful information:

> The data the describes the coordinates of the surface is set in `z`.
>   Data in `z` should be a {2D array}. Coordinates in `x` and `y` can
>   either be 1D {arrays} or {2D arrays} (e.g. to graph parametric
>   surfaces). If not provided in `x` and `y`, the x and y coordinates are
>   assumed to be linear starting at 0 with a unit step. The color scale
>   corresponds to the `z` values by default. For custom color scales, use
>   `surfacecolor` which should be a {2D array}, where its bounds can be
>   controlled using `cmin` and `cmax`.